how do I fix a 404 error when my Angular HttpClient can't find the API endpoint for retrieving
HttpClient can't find API endpoint: 404 Error when retrieving Pokémon data.
I'm using Angular's HttpClient module to fetch Pokémon data through a service. Here's my code for retrieving a single Pokémon by ID:

export class PokemonService {

getPokemonById(pokemonId: number): Observable<Pokemon | undefined> {
  return this.http.get<Pokemon>(`api/pokemon/${pokemonId}`).pipe(
    tap((response) => this.log(response)),
    catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, undefined))
  );
}
private log(response:Pokemon[]|Pokemon|undefined) {
    console.table(response);
  }

  private handleError (error:Error, errorValue:any ){
    console.error(error);
    return of(errorValue);
  }

}

const pokemonRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pokemon/:id', component: DetailPokemonComponent },
  { path: 'edit/pokemon/:id', component: EditPokemonComponent },
  { path: 'pokemons', component: ListPokemonComponent },
];

However, I'm getting a 404 error when trying to retrieve the data. My routes seem to be correct:
Solution:
It turns out that when using InMemoryDbService, the service expects API endpoints to be pluralized, meaning I need to add an "s" to the endpoint name. The correct endpoint would be api/pokemons/${pokemonId} instead of api/pokemon/${pokemonId}.
Could someone confirm if this is the right approach or if there’s another solution?

You haven't said how you set up the in-memory API, doesn't it just use the key in the object createDb returns? See the docs: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages/misc/angular-in-memory-web-api.

I think the the url should be https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId} -you forget add the https://pokeapi.co, unless you have an own API
